# rsync copies the current directory when I don't pass an option to my script

Tags: shell-script, rsync

Below is a script on Ubuntu 18.04 used to copy files from one directory to another. All works fine except the files from the current directory (`/media/rmerriam/Backup/rsync_backup`) are copied to the destination. They shouldn't be copied at all as they are never in the source path.

Manually executed (with and without `-s` makes no difference):

```
rmerriam@mysticlakelinux:/media/rmerriam/test/rsync_backup$ rsync -auv -s ../src/ ../dest
sending incremental file list

sent 59 bytes  received 12 bytes  142.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rmerriam@mysticlakelinux:/media/rmerriam/test/rsync_backup$ ls ../dest
```

Executed script without `-s`:

```
===========================
./merge.sh
 
 ../src/
 ../dest
rsync -auv  ../src/ ../dest
sending incremental file list
./    <====== added why???
merge.sh
merge_all.sh
merge_backups.sh

sent 3,124 bytes  received 76 bytes  6,400.00 bytes/sec
total size is 2,835  speedup is 0.89
rmerriam@mysticlakelinux:/media/rmerriam/test/rsync_backup$ ls ../dest
merge_all.sh  merge_backups.sh  merge.sh
```

Executed script with `-s` option:

```
rmerriam@mysticlakelinux:/media/rmerriam/test/rsync_backup$ ./merge.sh ../src/ ../dest -s
===========================
./merge.sh
 -s
 ../src/
 ../dest
rsync -auv -s ../src/ ../dest
sending incremental file list
./

sent 66 bytes  received 19 bytes  170.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rmerriam@mysticlakelinux:/media/rmerriam/test/rsync_backup$ ls ../dest
```

**Result:** manual execution and `-s` option didn't move the `$PWD` files. Without the `-s` the script copied the files.

The script without the `-s` added the `./` directory as a source directory. Why?

The command lines are shown by the `echo` and they are identical. Why different behavior in a script?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# base script for copying files to the common directory.
# only copies newer files

printf '===========================\n'
printf "$0\n $3\n $1\n $2\n"

echo rsync -auv "$3"    "$1" "$2"
rsync -auv "$3"    "$1" "$2"
```

For reference : `rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31`

Comment: In your script, are you 100% certain that `$PWD`, `$1`, and `$2` are correct at the point you call `rsync`? If you put something like `echo "PWD=$PWD, 1=$1, 2=$2."` immediately before the `rsync` do you get expected results? Do any of these three values contain whitespace? What evidence have you got that `rsync` keeps trying to copy the wrong files - if you delete them from the destination does it recopy them?

Comment: Show a complete, reproducible example. This means concrete values for the parameters, the content of the exclude file, and anything else that a reader would need to reproduce the problem. With what you've posted, the most likely explanation is that `$1` is not what you think. The secondmost likely explanation is that there's something weird in the exclude file.

Comment: @roaima, I've been outputting the directories so I would know the copies were in the proper places. Added my entire script to the op. Also simplified by removing the `exclude file`. Added actual output. Also moved the execution directory to sill another drive so it is away from $HOME, which is being copied.

Comment: It seems to be there's not a lot of point trying to continue addressing this question. The paths are being changed, which makes me suspect that the paths shown here in the question aren't actually the real ones, which in turn means we don't have a reproducible example. This is pretty much my VTC as "Unclear". @Gilles...?

Comment: @roaima The original was unclear: it showed a working script, and asked why the script wasn't working. Now that rm1948 has finally posted a script that does demonstrate the problem, and now that I've cleaned up the question to be comprehensible, this is a valid question.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'   I would have reworded the question if given the opportunity. Didn't read it in detail but it looked good. I was trying to maintain the original since some of the responses are now nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went looking at issues on `rsync` and found ["Empty quotes adds cwd to SRC directories"](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13901). I have a `$3` argument on the script for adding extra options. Often it is empty so this is the culprit. Adding the `-s` made the argument non-empty so avoided the issue.

This manual run confirms the issue:

```
rsync ""  -auv ../src/ ../dest
sending incremental file list
created directory ../dest
./
merge.sh
merge_all.sh
merge_backups.sh

sent 3,124 bytes  received 106 bytes  6,460.00 bytes/sec
total size is 2,835  speedup is 0.88
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in your script. Arguably there's also a bug in rsync, because it's silently doing something surprising when you pass it weird data, whereas it would be better for it to error out. But either way your script doesn't work.

The problematic line is:

```
rsync -auv "$3"    "$1" "$2"
```

When the third argument of the script (`"$3"`) starts with a `-`, this is an option for rsync. But when the third argument does not start with a `-`, which includes the case where the script only has two arguments (or less), this is a non-option argument. Rsync accepts multiple source directories, so when `"$3"` doesn't start with a `-`, you're asking it to copy `"$3"` and `"$1"` to `"$2"`. For example,

```
./merge.sh ../src/ ../dest
```

tells rsync to copy both the empty string and `../src/` to `../dest`.

Most applications reject the empty string when they're looking for a file name. However, in so far as the empty string is accepted as a file name, it means the current directory. It's coherent with how relative paths are transformed into absolute paths: if a path is relative (doesn't start with `/`), then prepend the absolute path to the current working directory and a slash, and you get an equivalent absolute path. If you apply this to the empty string, which is a relative path since it doesn't start with a slash, you get the current working directory with a slash at the end, which is the current working directory.

Rsync accepts the empty string as meaning the current directory. So it's doing exactly what you're telling it.

Arguably, passing the empty string as an argument is more likely to be a mistake than something deliberate. The shortest widely acceptable way of specifying the current directory is `.` (a dot). So arguably rsync should print an error message saying that the argument is invalid and error out.

You want your script to accept an optional extra option, but the way you've implemented it, the extra option is mandatory. To make it optional, check whether the script has a third argument.

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
  echo >&2 "$0: too few arguments (SRC and DEST are required)"
  exit 120
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  rsync -auv "$1" "$2"
elif [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
  rsync -auv "$3" "$1" "$2"
else
  echo >&2 "$0: too many arguments (only one OPTIONS argument is permitted)"
  exit 120
fi
```

This is a weird interface though: why accept at most one option? You might as well accept an arbitrary number of options (why can't I pass `-q --dry-run`?). It would be both simpler for the user to understand and simpler to implement. Furthermore, the convention is to pass options *before* non-option arguments, not after. Once the interface is simplified to accept an arbitrary number of options, you can simplify the code to

```
rsync -auv "$@"
```

Comment: Appreciate the recognition of the bug in `rsync` and, somewhat less so, the suggestions on BASH scripting. The advice is good but as you are well aware you start with something working and keep working on it without always finessing the details. Since this is only for my temporary use there was no need to clean things up. If `rsync` didn't have a bug there would never have been a need to revise the script.

Comment: @rm1948 If rsync didn't have this bug, your script would only have made rsync display an error, it wouldn't have worked.